# Would an attacker knowing the block-heights of my wallet's transactions weaken my privacy/security?

Tags: privacy, security, block-height

Let's say I'd go through all the transactions in my wallet, write down their block-heights and store this list somewhere insecure.

Could my privacy or security be compromised by this in any way (assuming an attacker knows it is a list of block-heights for all of my wallet's transactions)?

Comment: Kinda by definition, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would weaken your privacy. By knowing *when* you transacted, an attacker can narrow down the field of which possible outputs you own, thus increasing their capability to trace your past and future transactions.

Comment: Does this only work if the attacker has other information with which to cross-reference the list of block-heights? Or do you mean if an attacker knows that a certain list of blocks all contain transactions of one-and-the-same person, then that might be enough to determine which transactions those are?

Comment: Knowing any one piece of information alone is not significant, but with other information it builds a case. If I know you have transacted at given times (block heights), and I happen to know a receiving parties transaction times, I can begin to prove you transacted with that other party. Bottom line, whenever you leak *any* data, you weaken your privacy.